# Jquery, javascript - select a element by class with bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, validation

How can I get a element by class with brackets?
example:

```
<input class="validation[required,onlyNumber]">
<input class="validation[required]">
...
$(something-here).blur(function(){...});
```

How can I set a validation for both required?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[class^=validation]').blur(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Brackets` and `commas` are meta characters so you should escape it first.

Try,

```
$('.validation\\[required\\,onlyNumber\\]')
$('.validation\\[required\\]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [**^** Attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('input[class^="validation"]').blur(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $('.validation\\[required\\,onlyNumber\\]')
```

As per [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all input that have class containing `[` using this selector:

```
$('input[class*="["]').blur(function(){...});
```

if you still want to use [] ,escape them using `\\` :

```
$('input.validation\\[required\\').blur(function(){...});
```

Check this fiddle: [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/45WJs/)

Comment: please mark this answer as valide so that it helps others , thanks